# How we can Remove Dynamically added Fragments from layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can any one help me.
I have a Fragment say FRAGMENT A  and am adding it to a layout dynamically...Suppose i have added 3 instance of FRAGMENT A to that layout.Then How i can Remove that  3 Fragment instance programmatically.I tried google searches and also another stackoverflow threads but they are not working..

PLease help me

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

it's actually pretty simple:

let's say you added the fragment like this:

```
fragmentTransac.add(R.id.content, fragA);
```

instead, you'll add it with a TAG too

```
fragmentTransac.add(R.id.content, new FragA(), "first");
// then the other
fragmentTransac.add(R.id.content, new FragA(), "second");
```

then to remove:

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("first");
if(f!=null) fragmentTransac.remove(f);
fragmentTransac.commit();
```

happy coding =]

Comment: hi,thanks for your help...but its not working..can you suggest another way

Comment: that IS the way. If it's not working it's because it's not being correctly implemented. Did you understand that the object `fragmentTransac` I put in the example is the FragmentTransaction that is usually obtained from getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()? Also if you're using the compatibility pack instad of getFragmentmanager() you should call getSupportFragmentManager()? I didn't include those details because they are quite basic.

Comment: ye i knpw those things...i put like thisFragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("hi");
      FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ft.remove(f);

Comment: are you forgetting to commit() ?

Comment: Thankyou Very Much, It Saved My Time :)

Comment: You are amazing. So clear your solution so happy we are